# Inverse Hyperbolic Tangent type Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a name for this series?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{2k}}{2k}.$$

I know that:

$$\tanh^{-1}(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{2k-1}}{2k-1}.$$

Comment: $$-\log(1-z)-\tanh^{-1}(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{2k}$$

Comment: Yup I noticed. Was curious, if there is a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a name for the series you have there, but,

$$\begin{align*}
-\log(1-z)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k}\\
-\log(1-z^2)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{k}\\
-\frac12\log(1-z^2)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{2k}\\
\log\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{2k}\\
\end{align*}$$